# XCode precompiling pch twice; second time with wrong language

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pch

I have an Objective C project in XCode.  When building, XCode precompiles my prefix PCH file twice.  The first time, it uses the arguments `-x objective-c-header`, and it works fine.  The second time, it uses `-x c-header`, and it fails (due to the file containing Objective C code).

I have another project that's set up the same, but it builds fine.  (The PCH is only precompiled once, with Objective C.)  I compared the build settings for the two projects side-by-side, and nothing relevant differed.  I compared the build settings for the targets side-by-side, and again, no relevant differences.

I tried cleaning all targets and rebuilding, but no luck.  I tried restarting XCode, but no luck.  I grepped my project folder for `c-header`, but it only showed up in the build logs.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hate answering my own question, but I figured it out.  I disabled precompiling the prefix header to see if that would let me continue working.  The build still failed with the same error, but it failed when including the file from a .c file I forgot I had in the project.  Apparently, the existence of this .c file is the difference between this project and the other.  Now that I know what's going on, I moved my code inside the `#ifdef __OBJC__`, and everything seems fine.

Answer (score 7):

The PCH file is being rebuilt multiple times because there is multiple languages in your project; once with the objective-c compiler and once with the straight C file, thus that you had Objective-C code outside of the **OBJC** #ifdef and that caused the straight C compiler to hoark up it's lunch.

If you had a C++ file, you'd probably end up with 3 PCH compilations (IIRC -- been a while since I mucked with that).