# XCode precompiling .pch multiple times

Tags: xcode, xctool

I am optimizing the Xcode build speed. From the Travis build log, I have seen that Xcode precompiles the same pch file 4 times.

```
  ✓ Precompile Pods-CKCountdownButton-CKCountdownButton-prefix.pch (1946 ms)
  ✓ Precompile Pods-CKCountdownButton-CKCountdownButton-prefix.pch (1935 ms)
  ✓ Precompile Pods-CKCountdownButton-CKCountdownButton-prefix.pch (1338 ms)
  ✓ Precompile Pods-CKCountdownButton-CKCountdownButton-prefix.pch (1307 ms)
```

The full build log can be found https://travis-ci.org/cybertk/CKCountdownButton/builds/31503539

How can I reduce the building time by precompiling pch file only 1 time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode precompiling pch twice; second time with wrong language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091489/xcode-precompiling-pch-twice-second-time-with-wrong-language)